# Why doesn't this CSS menu work?

Tags: html, css, menu

I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working properly. It's supposed to be a generic dropdown css menu. I haven't gotten to the part where I make the dropdown list invisible (I'll set display: none when I get to it, lol) but for now I'm just trying to get the layout right. However, the part that isn't working the way I want it to is the actual dropdown part. It is supposed to hover over the page content, but instead it seems to be pushing it down even though I set a z-index. Anyone know why?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <div id="nav-container">
        <ul id="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">PAGE 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="page3.html">PAGE 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="page4.html">PAGE 4</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="test.html">TEST</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="test2.html">TEST 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content-container">
CONTENT GOES HERE
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#navigation {
    position: relative;
    top: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #179326;
    z-index: 5;
}

#nav-container{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#nav li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #179326;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "Archivo Narrow", arial, sans-serif;
}

#nav li a {
    display: block;
    min-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 25px 0px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background-color: #00691e;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `z-index` only really matters when content can be placed on top of each other. And that is only possible when the [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) is not static.

In your case, the inner list is placed within the `li` according to the normal flow, and as such is respected when calculating the `li`’s height. The height is carried over to the outer list which then pushes the content down.

To fix this, you need to make the inner list not add up to the height of the list item. To do that, set the position to `absolute`.

Comment: It works now. I learned something new about z-index today, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You need `position: absolute` on the submenu, otherwise it is still part of the document flow and will add height when visible.